# How to add Text under a MahApps MetroCircleButtonStyle icon?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, mahapps.metro

I am using the MahApps Metro controls in a WPF application with their FlyOut control on the bottom of the window. I am using their MetroCircleButtonStyle button like so:

```
    <Button Width="55"
        Height="55"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
  <Rectangle Width="20"
              Height="20">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                    Visual="{StaticResource appbar_city}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>  
</Button>
```

My question is how do I add Text below these icons in the flyout?

Steve

Answer (score 5):

something like:

```
<Button Width="55"
        Height="55"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Rectangle Width="20"
                Height="20">
      <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                      Visual="{StaticResource appbar_city}" />
      </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

[image]

**Update:**

`MetroCircleButtonStyle` by itself does not accomodate for Text outside the Ellipse. It's `Template` is pretty much a Grid with 1 cell and 3 children on top of each other(`Ellipse`, Another `Ellipse` and top-most is the `ContentPresenter`). Text inside does not actually respond to any state change either, So text outside with this Style is as good as wrapping the `Button` without text with a `TextBlock` in say a `StackPanel`.

What you're looking for, you could use the [AppBarButton](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/AppBarButton.xaml). Do note the documentation states, `Due to issues with this control, AppBarButton is due to be removed for v1.0` so use that as an example and build up your own control with a similar `Style`. Probably drop the `ViewBox`, if your `Button` sizes are fixed.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, already tried this not what I was wanting. Need the Text below the circle not inside the circle. I just thought MahApps might have already allowed some property for this format someway?

Comment: @Orgbrat check my update. You could take a hint from the obsolete `AppBarButton` for what you require and derive it yourself. I've given a link to the GitPage for that control's `Style`. Check if you can address your issue with that.

Comment: @Orgbrat Did you ever figure out anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

From [Viv's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18300521) answer, you can add margin on the textbox element to push the label down:

```
<Button Width="55"
        Height="55"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Rectangle Width="20"
                Height="20">
      <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                      Visual="{StaticResource appbar_city}" />
      </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```